# Job title of an owner of income-generating real estate properties?

Tags: pronoun, proper-noun

If an individual (in no way incorporated nor employing other staff) **owns** several properties in a city in their own name, and lives off collecting **rent** from residential as well as commercial tenants in these properties, what would their "beruf" be in German?

Even in English, I can't put a name to it. "**Property manager**" is often a title given to an employee who oversees and lives in one of the buildings, and therefore does not sufficiently describe the fact that the individual *owns* them, whereas "**real estate investor**" sounds aloof.

Looking for something formal to put on an application form, but at the same time modest, assuming it is a portfolio of no more than 10 buildings

Comment: I'd kindly suggest not to immediately accept the first answer that has been provided. This leaves little time for others to provide alternative suggestions, as well as to figure out (in comments etc.) whether the suggested answer has any flaws or drawbacks.

Comment: The more I think about this question, the more I think more context might be helpful, *e.g.* do need this job-title for a tax form or a chat on a party?

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: Man kann jederzeit eine andere, später gegebene Antwort zur akzeptierten erklären. Es gibt keinen Grund eine bessere Antwort zurückzuhalten, nur weil eine bereits gegebene zur besten gekürt wurde.

Comment: @userunknown: "Es gibt keinen Grund eine bessere Antwort zurückzuhalten, nur weil eine bereits gegebene zur besten gekürt wurde." - man kann durchaus davon ausgehen, dass genau das passiert, und zwar sowohl aus Unerfahrenheit mit Stack Exchange (Annahme: "Ist bereits eine Antwort akzeptiert, interessiert die Frage vermutlich ohnehin keinen mehr.") als auch aus Erfahrenheit mit Stack Exchange (Annahme: "Was nützt es noch, eine Antwort zu schreiben, auch wenn sie besser als die akzeptierte ist? Allzu oft wollte der OP nur eine schnelle Antwort und kommt nicht wieder.").

Comment: Im letzten Fall ist Dein Kommentar aber auch in den Wind gesprochen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

People who live off their assets can be called [*Privatier*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Privatier) in German. However, this term is old-fashioned. It also does not specify that the person makes a living from real estate (could as well be capital interest or stock they are managing).

I would say *Selbstständiger Vermieter* might be appropriate for the situation you describe. It means "self-employed landlord".

Comment: I somewhat disagree with this suggestion - to me, "selbständig" implies the person is in some way running a small company (at least with a "Gewerbeschein" or something like that). In fact, I'd wonder what's the difference to a Vermieter who is *not* "selbständig".

Comment: what do you recommend instead

Comment: and i think it's normal for companies to consist of only one person with no other employees

Comment: @user610620: Absolutely. But the mere fact of owning and renting out one or more places to live in doesn't mean you are a company.

Comment: I meant in the sense that Dr. John Doe is automatically a company, in the case of selbständig physicians

Comment: @user610620: No-one is "automatically" a company, I'd say. Being/having a "company" has quite some legal implications - using the word while claiming those implications aren't present doesn't make any sense to me, for a "company", or similar terms related to organisational entities of work, (well, at least in German) is inherently a legal thing rather than anything else.

Comment: don't worry "automatic" was an intentional exaggeration, given that paperwork needed to register one's own name as a self-employed professional should have been pretty obvious

Comment: @user610620: And it's exactly that paperwork that never happened for someone who "just" rents out a couple of places. That's why I think terms that evoke the image of any kind of "company" or "freelance" arrangement are unfortunate. (Rest assured, they still have to do a lot of paperwork for taxes etc., but that's not the paperwork we were referring to here.) But I think we are on the same page concerning the implied meanings now.

Answer (score 1):

In general, a person who is wealthy enough to make a living without having a paid job or without financial assistance is called a *[Privatier](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Privatier)* ([pʁivaˈtjeː). However, this doesn't specify, where the wealth comes from.

A bit more specific is the term *[Rentier](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rentier_(Person))* ([rɛnˈti̯eː]). This describes someone, who lives off regular payments from capital invested in stocks or bonds, renting real estate, or leasing land.

Both terms are a old fashioned, but not completely out-dated.

Comment: rentier doesn't exclusively single out real estate as the source of income

Comment: I would also caution that in writing, "Rentier" looks absolutely the same as the German word for "reindeer". Lacking any context, and especially given the relative obscurity of the word as described here, the term is guaranteed to cause some confusion.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper I assume one could differentiate them based on context an genus  (masculine *vs* neuter). But without context and articles it will be difficult, true.

Comment: @Arsak: True! I was thinking of statements like "Er hat seinen Job an den Nagel gehängt und ist jetzt ein Rentier."

Comment: @user610620 No, but that's the most specific one I could think of, despite just saying *"Ich bin Vermieter und lebe von meinen Mieteinnahmen."*

Comment: And what exactly is so bad with that last one? I think it's by far the best answer.

Comment: @tofro Well, I can understand that this is not satisfying for someone who looks for a very specific term that only includes income from renting real estate, but excludes other types of regular income. I'm just not sure if this exists

Answer (score 1):

Die Bezeichnung *Privatier* ist hier unpassend. Ein Privatier ist eine Person, die ohne tätig werden zu müssen von ihrem – zumeist ererbten oder beim Verkauf eines eigenen Unternehmens erhaltenen – Vermögen leben kann. Ein Wohnungseigentümer, der mit der Verwaltung seiner Wohnungen beschäftigt ist, ist gerade kein Privatier, denn er arbeitet ja – und wer einmal mehrere Wohnungen besessen oder in einer Wohnbauverwaltung gearbeitet hat, weiß gut wieviel Arbeit die wechselnden Mieter, die anfallenden Reparaturen, die Rechtsstreitigkeiten und so weiter machen.

Privatpersonen, die Wohneigentum besitzen, sind in der Regel nicht hauptberufliche Vermieter, sondern legen das in ihrem Brotberuf (als Ingenieure, Ärzte, Handwerksmeister und so weiter) erworbene Geld statt auf der Bank in Immobilien an. Wer so viele Wohnungen besitzt, dass er deren Vermietung zu seinem Hauptberuf macht, der gründet klugerweise ein Unternehmen, allein schon um im Fall von Schadensforderungen nicht mit seinem Privatvermögen zu haften.

Dass jemand als Privatperson viele Wohnungen besitzt und allein davon lebt scheint mir deshalb eine Ausnahme, für die es meines Wissens auch keine eigene Bezeichnung gibt. Diese Person ist, wie alle anderen Wohnungseigentümer auch, **Wohnungseigentümer** und **Vermieter**. Beides ist kein Beruf.

Der **Immobilienkaufmann** dagegen, hat eine Ausbildung gemacht und vermietet gewerbsmäßig Wohnungen, die üblicherweise aber nicht ihm sondern dem Unternehmen gehören, für das er arbeitet, oder Privatpersonen, die sich gegenüber den Mietern durch sein Unternehmen vertreten lassen.

Comment: Daß Vermieten auch Arbeit bedeutet und deshalb eine Person, die von Mieteinkünften lebt, kein Privatier sein könne, finde ich unsinnig, da die Mieteinkünfte nicht in unmittelbarem Zusammenhang mit dieser Arbeit stehen. Ob der Vermieter jeden Tag bei seinen Mietern auf der Matte stehen muß oder sich an seine Villa am Starnberger See zurückzieht – die Mieteinkünfte bleiben die gleichen. Gäbe es denn überhaupt noch Privatiers, wenn die Betreuung des eigenen Vermögens als Arbeit gewertet würde?

Comment: @DavidVogt: "Ob der Vermieter jeden Tag bei seinen Mietern auf der Matte stehen muß oder sich an seine Villa am Starnberger See zurückzieht – die Mieteinkünfte bleiben die gleichen." - das würde ich so nicht unterschreiben. Es kann nämlich gut sein, dass die Mieteinkünfte früher oder später wegbrechen, wenn sich der Vermieter nicht hinreichend um die Immobilie kümmert (und dabei spielt es keine Rolle, ob er es versäumt, selber vor Ort neue Glühbirnen im Treppenhaus anzubringen oder aus der Ferne Handwerker zu beauftragen) oder Mieter einfach nicht zahlen. Zudem kann auch den Vermieter ...

Comment: ... Post vom Anwalt erreichen (auch am Starnberger See!), wenn er seinen vertraglichen oder gesetzlichen Pflichten als Vermieter nicht nachkommt.

Comment: Please consider adding an English translation of your answer. For further discussion of this, see https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1048/should-the-language-of-an-answer-match-the-language-used-in-the-question

Comment: @DavidVogt Wenn du deutsche Textkorpora durchschaust und dich damit vertraut machst, wie der Begriff *Privatier* verwendet wird, wirst du feststellen, dass er üblicherweise von Vorstellungen begleitet wird wie großem Reichtum, dem Rückzug von jedweder Erwerbstätigkeit, und dass die Person sich fortan, bar aller Sorgen, dem widmet, das Leben zu genießen. Ich bin Vermieter und kann dir versichern, dass ich das als Arbeit empfinde, nicht genieße und es mir oftmals Sorgen macht. Mein Plan ist, wenn ich in Rente gehe, das Haus zu verkaufen und *dann* von dem Geld zu leben wie ein Privatier.